# How to program Android 13 data partition restore?

Tags: android, encryption

I'm working on TWRP, transfering data, apps and settings from one phone to another (same phone model). The backup is working, creates a bunch of tar files (.win???) containing all files (unencrypted) of the data partition (except the keys). For the restore, I have to use a somewhat messy method. Otherwise I get a bootloop. Scripting to test restoring is currently as follows:

- phone is in factory reset
- restore everything but misc:

  ```
    for archname in data.f2fs.win???
        do
            echo "extracting $archname..."
            tar --exclude="/data/misc" --exclude="/data/misc_ce" --exclude="/data/misc_de" -xpvzf $archname
        done
  ```
- start the phone once and shut it down again
- restore misc except the keys data/misc/keystore und data/misc/vold:

  ```
  for archname in data.f2fs.win???
    do
        echo "extracting $archname..."
        tar -xpvzf $archname /data/misc /data/misc_ce /data/misc_de
    done
  ```

The phone works almost completely ok with all apps and settings. However I noticed a) and b).

**a) iogp**

The system process /system_ext/bin/iopgp kept crashing. Logcat:

```
3539  3539 E iopgp   : SQLite error (14): cannot open file at line 39847 of [bcd014c473]
3539  3539 E iopgp   : SQLite error (14): os_unix.c:39847: (13) lstat(/data/misc/iopgp/sqlite.db) -
3539  3539 F iopgp   : dbmodel.h:403] Failed to open DB: unable to open database file
```

However, /data/misc/iopgp/sqlite.db is present and ok. (I can open it in an SQLite Viewer.)
Access rights from the directory and file compared to a working phone are the same:

```
drwxr-x--- 18 system system 3488  2023-09-15 17:06 iopgp
-rw------- 1  system system 32768 2023-09-15 16:13 sqlite.db
```

ps of the process:

```
system        3613     1 2373416  10020 binder_ioctl_write_read 0 S iopgp
```

Workaround: I can delete sqlite.db. It is automatically recreated. No crash anymore.

How comes that iopgp does not "see" the file?
Maybe this is related to Androids FBE (file-based encryption).
What is required for a process to access a file on the data partition of Android 13?

**b) DeskClock**

A rather similar problem with com.oneplus.deskclock accessing its database file
/data/user_de/0/com.oneplus.deskclock/databases/alarms.db.
Workaround: pm uninstall --user 0 com.oneplus.deskclock, pm install-existing com.oneplus.deskclock.

Currently I don't see more fatal errors when operating the phone. But I'm not sure if there are any surprises lurking.
In addition, with the workarounds I rely on the system "repairing itself", restoring the files resp. file access itself. This will not work in every case.
So, I am looking for more insights. Either to correct my restore method or to have means to fix problems afterwards.

I would be glad if someone has an idea what is happening here,

Zweikeks

Comment: It seems that the SELinux file contexts need to be restored. See my answer [File permissions of Android 13 on data partition](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/253566/397251)